# JavaScript: Dispatch event from one class and listen in another class

Tags: javascript

Can I dispatch event from one class and listen it in another class in JAVASCRIPT. Can any one help me regarding this.

```
function onButtonClickHandler(){ alert("Testing Add event listener"); }
test.addEventListener("buttonClick",onButtonClickHandler);
```

Comment: People mean different things by "class" when they're talking about javascript, so we'd really need to see your code.  But in general, yes, you can create an event listener anywhere.  When that event happens (or is triggered), it will trigger your listener.

Comment: function onButtonClickHandler(){
 alert("testdot com");
}
this.addEventListener("buttonClick",onButtonClickHandler); this is 1st .js fine and i am dispatching from another js function

Comment: @Brenda: Please share your code, you are still sharing some parts here and there. We don't know what you want to do if you don't share some sample code with us.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
test.addEventListener("click",onButtonClickHandler);
```

Comment: this is not a user action click event dispatch. I have a function which will be called. when that function is called I need to dispatch a event and listen it in another js

Comment: @Brenda: Remind me, why would you like to do this in "pure" JavaScript and not use a framework, such as the amazing jQuery, to add custom event listeners and trigger them any way you like?

Comment: jQuery needs every thing with respect to element. In my case I cannot have an element always.

Comment: @Brenda: Where are you going to attach the event then, if you don't attach it to the DOM?